# DataFrame.stack() made Series

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, stack, series

typed pd.DataFrame.stack() to make DataFrame, but the result showed me that Series made.

like following,

[image]

after I saw that result, deleted .stack(), and showed following result.

[image]

what's difference between these trials?

Answer (score 1):

You need assign output, because after [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) you got `Series`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'theoretic':[1.5,2.8,3.1],
                   'simulation':[4.7,5.8,6.2]})

print (df)
   simulation  theoretic
0         4.7        1.5
1         5.8        2.8
2         6.2        3.1

df = df.stack()

print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

df = df.reset_index()

print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (df)
   level_0     level_1    0
0        0  simulation  4.7
1        0   theoretic  1.5
2        1  simulation  5.8
3        1   theoretic  2.8
4        2  simulation  6.2
5        2   theoretic  3.1
```